# Return string but don't echo to the screen

Tags: php, return

I am trying to understand the `return` keyword and its functionality, however, I am getting a little confused.

I have read [this](https://www.w3resource.com/php/statement/return.php) which has been a good starting point, but I can't seem to understand the solution to what I imagine is a very simple problem.

Say I have a PHP file called **index.php** and I call a function from it like so (imagine it's not being called from within a class or function);

```
echo $fun -> editAnswer ($obj->answer_id, $obj->answerString ,$obj->correct, $questionID, $lecturer_id);
```

Then in my **function.php**  I have:

```
public function editAnswer($answer_id, $answerString, $correct, $questionID, $lecturer_id){

     $db = $this -> db;


     if (!empty ($answer_id) && !empty ($answerString) && !empty($correct) && !empty($questionID) && !empty ($lecturer_id)){


         $result = $db -> editAnswer($answer_id, $answerString, $correct, $questionID, $lecturer_id);

         if ($result) {

           return "The Updates To Your Answer Have Been Saved!";


         } else {

            $response["result"] = "failure";
            $response["message"] = "The Updates To Your Answer Have Not Been Saved, Please Try Again";
            return json_encode($response);

         }

   } else {

      return $this -> getMsgParamNotEmpty();

   }
}
```

If successful, I will return the string `The Updates To Your Answer Have Been Saved!`, however, this will be immediately echoed to the screen of **index.php**.

My thinking is that if after calling the function, the user was still on **index.php**, it might look a little ugly to have a string at the top of the page. Maybe I would want to catch the returned string and then create an alert dialog before displaying it.

How would I go about doing something like that rather than immediately echoing the returned string?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand you, but you can assign the method "response" into a variable, for example $temp =  $fun -> editAnswer ($obj->answer_id, $obj->answerString ,$obj->correct, $questionID, $lecturer_id); And then use the $temp variable anywhere else in the page.

Comment: Save the returned value in a variable, or call and echo the value only when you actually need to. I don't understand the problem

Comment: Thanks guys - that is a simple solution, I was just having a funny 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value is echoed because you use `echo` to output the result.

Save the result to a variable and use it later

```
$result = $fun -> editAnswer ($obj->answer_id, $obj->answerString ,$obj->correct, $questionID, $lecturer_id);

echo "we called the function"
echo "the result was $result"
```